# Custom name to the war file for spring boot application with external tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, web-deployment, contextpath

I have created a war file for spring boot application com#myApp.war, when I deploy it to external tomcat it works fine with the url http://localhost:8080/com/myApp/healthcheck. But I need to rename com#myApp.war to com.war while the url should remain the same. I have mentioned my pom.xml for creating war file below.

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>app.com.myApp</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.myApp</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <name>COM</name>
    

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>19.3.0.0</version>
<!--            <scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        </dependency>-->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
<!--        This gives the final war file name-->
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.2</version>
<!--                This help us to get buil info, used in healthcheck-->
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>build-info</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build-info</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

How can I create a war file with the name com.war but should work with url
http://localhost:8080/com/myApp/healthcheck

Comment: Provide a deployment descriptor which instructs which URL to use. Create a `context.xml` in the `META-INF` directory (see https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context) which you can then use to configure all sorts of things for your application.

Comment: Any example how to use it properly?

Comment: Have you read the documentation which is linked? That contains all the information.

Comment: I can up with this , I created file com.xml in the \home\apache-tomcat-9.0.40\conf\Catalina\localhost\ directory , like this <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/com/myApp" docBase="$CATALINA_BASE/conf/Catalina/localhost/com.war.default"/>

Comment: I can up with this , I created file com.xml in the \home\apache-tomcat-9.0.40\conf\Catalina\localhost\ directory , like this <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/com/myApp" docBase="$CATALINA_BASE/conf/Catalina/localhost/com.war"/> but its the same problem as before I cannot use this url  http://localhost:8080/com/myApp/healthcheck but http://localhost:8080/com/healthcheck works

Comment: @M.Deinum: when using automatic deployment, the `path` attribute of the deployment descriptor is (theoretically) ignored (cf. [Automatic Application Deployment](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/host.html#Automatic_Application_Deployment)). The WAR files in `webapps` must conform to the naming convention.

Comment: One more thing , while creating the new war file (com.war), I renamed artifactId of the application from com.myApp to com, does this make any problem

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz is right I see the message of docBase  and path attribute being ignored in the tomcat logs.

Comment: The problem with the `name com#myApp.war is that the external tomcat has security manager installed. Even though I use the following in catalina.policy
grant codeBase "file:${catalina.base}/webapps/com/-" {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};  the url localhost:8080/com/myApp/healthcheck  does not work

Comment: @SyedIftekharuddin: if that is your concern, then you should use `"file:${catalina.base}/webapps/com#myApp/-` (assuming your Tomcat unpacks WARs). Anyway, why use a security manager, if you end up granting all permissions?